# Oracle join returning too many rows

Tags: oracle, inner-join

I have the following select statments in Oracle 19:

```
select count(*) as facility_load_stg_cnt from facility_load_stg;

select count(*) as facility_cnt from facility;

select count(*) as loctn_typ_cnt from loctn_typ;

select count(*) as join_cnt from (
select f.facility_id, lt.loctn_typ_id
from facility_load_stg stg
inner join facility f on stg.facility_cd = f.facility_cd
inner join loctn_typ lt on stg.bldg = lt.loctn_typ_nm);
```

the object is simple, get the PK's for facility and loctn_typ (facility_id, loctn_typ_id) to insert into the table that will build the relationship.

The problem is when I run the above code, I get these results:

```
FACILITY_LOAD_STG_CNT
---------------------
                  987


FACILITY_CNT
------------
         645


LOCTN_TYP_CNT
-------------
          188


  JOIN_CNT
----------
      2905
```

why is the select with the join have 3x the rows of the facility_load_stg table?  I am sure I am doing something silly, I just cannot see it.

Folks have asked to see the table definitions, here is the relavent parts:

```
create table FACILITY_MAINT_DATA.FACILITY_LOAD_STG
(
    FACILITY_CD VARCHAR2(100) not null,
    BLDG VARCHAR2(100)
)

create table FACILITY_MAINT_DATA.FACILITY
(
    FACILITY_CD VARCHAR2(100),
    FACILITY_ID NUMBER(14) not null
        constraint PK_FACILITY
            primary key
)

create table FACILITY_MAINT_DATA.LOCTN_TYP
(
    LOCTN_TYP_ID NUMBER(14) default "FACILITY_MAINT_DATA"."LOCTN_TYP_ID_SEQ"."NEXTVAL" not null
        constraint PK_LOCTN_TYP
            primary key,
    LOCTN_TYP_NM VARCHAR2(100),
)
```

Comment: What are your table definitions and what does your data look like?  Presumably, you're joining on something other than the primary key.  If multiple rows in `f` or in `lt` match the join criteria for a single row in `stg`, your join would generate more rows than are in `stg`.

Comment: We can't answer, but we can speculate. You didn't explain what the `*_cd` things are, and why you are joining on them instead of the `*_id` columns, if those are the primary keys. Several facilities, for example, may have the same "code" (guessing at what "cd" may mean), even if they are distinct facilities. In which case the joining is probably wrong/incorrect/doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Try something like select facility_cd,count(*) from facility_cnt group by facility_cd; and select loctn_typ_nm,count(*) from loctn_typ_cnt group by loctn_typ_nm; - if you see a facility_cd or loctn_typ_nm value with count > 1 then you know that the join from facility_load_stg_cnt on those columns could join to more than one row in those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generall rule if you join and you encounter a *higher count* that you expect is that the *join keys are not unique**

Here a simple example reproducting the same result as you have (limiting only to two tables).

```
create table tab1 as
select rownum id, 
case when rownum <= 80 then 'CD_'||rownum else 'CD_X' end cd from dual connect by level <= 645;

create table tab2 as
select rownum id, 
case when rownum <= 80 then 'CD_'||rownum 
when rownum <= 85 then 'CD_X'
else 'CD_Y' end cd from dual connect by level <= 987;

select count(*) from tab1;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       645

select count(*) from tab2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       987

select count(*) 
from tab1
join tab2
on tab1.cd = tab2.cd;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      2905
```

**Summary** change the join to use the unique keys or limit the join only to such `CD`columns that are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the comments, that got me looking at detail at the actual data and there are duplications.  Now I just have to figure out why, just need some investigation:)